# Pour émuler le terme anglais « whiskers » un terme d'une plus grande spécificité que « moustache »

Tags: vocabulaire, synonymes, terminologie

En français il est courant de parler de ces longs poils plus ou moins épais que certains animaux ont de part et d'autre de la gueule en les appelant collectivement une moustache (en anglais on dit « whisker » (un poil), ce qui souligne un certain côté inadéquat du nom français et motive un peu ma question).

[image]

Le TLFi fournit un terme synonyme dans la terminologie scientifique, *vibrisse* (un poil), qui est souvent mentionné comme synonyme, mais sans précision quant à l'usage.

Il n'y a pas de doute que dès qu'un ouvrage touche un peu à l'aspect scientifique d'un sujet, ce terme soit reconnu comme approprié ([vibrisses](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vibrisses%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moustache)) **moustache** B.− P. anal., gén. au plur.
>
> 1. Longs poils tactiles très sensibles poussant sur le museau de certains mammifères. Synon. vibrisses. Moustaches du phoque. Le nain difforme tirait la queue du singe et les moustaches du chat, dont l'un glapissait et l'autre jurait (Gautier, Rom. momie,1858, p. 260).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vibrisse)) **vibrisse** C. − ZOOL. Long poil tactile disposé sur la face, près de la bouche ou sur les pattes de nombreux mammifères (d'apr. Zool., t. 3, 1972, p. 586 [Encyclop. de la Pléiade]). Vibrisses du chat (Lar. Lang. fr.).

Deux questions qui vont de pair me semble mériter l'avis de la communauté.

1. Dans quelle mesure est-ce que l'on trouverait le terme scientifique « vibrisse » bien ou mal utilisé dans les contextes non scientifiques ?
2. Existe-t-il en français courant un terme qui serait évidemment beaucoup moins utilisé que « moustache » (même un terme régional) , mais à l'exemple de « whiskers » en anglais, un terme qui permettrait d'éviter l'abus de dénomination ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141581/discussion-on-question-by-lph-pour-emuler-le-terme-anglais--whiskers--un-terme).

Answer (score 4):

Comme l'indique le TLFi (ou [Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9M3043)), l'emploi de *moustache* (emprûnt de l'italien) pour les poils tactiles sur le museau des animaux est généralement au pluriel (*les moustaches*), ce qui diffère en nombre de l'emploi courant chez l'humain pour l'« ensemble des poils qui poussent au-dessus de la lèvre supérieure » (Ac.9). Il s'agit d'une extension de sens par analogie pour ces « grandes [soie](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/soie/73223)s tactiles » et elle remonte à 1575 (DHLF/Rey). Personne ne semble s'en être plaint depuis près d'un demi millénaire.

Une comparaison avec le mot anglais [*whisker(s)*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/whisker) n'étaye aucune inadéquation ou abus de dénomination en français : le sens de poil au visage (l'emploi pour la moustache serait [vieilli](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whisker) ; il s'agira des [favoris](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9F0363) ou des poils au menton<sup>1</sup>) apparaît avant celui visant l'animal, que ce soit dans la présentation lexicale (donc l'importance), ou [étymologiquement](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=whisker) (1600 pour le premier, 1670 pour le second). De plus :

> La richesse d'une langue, c’est sa capacité de répondre aux besoins
> expressifs de ses locuteurs et de ses locutrices; c’est l’abondance de
> ses mots, sans doute, mais aussi et surtout leur flexibilité, leur
> aptitude à construire des significations multiples, à exprimer la
> réalité dans toute sa complexité. ([BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources-linguistiques/chroniques/chroniques-linguistiques/une-langue-un-nombre-infini-de-mots))

L'analogie comme la métaphore participent de l'[enrichissement lexical](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23203/la-redaction-et-la-communication/figures-de-style/figures-jouant-sur-le-sens/la-metaphore). *Les mots les plus souvent utilisés sont souvent polysémiques* ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polys%C3%A9mie)) et on retrouve même des mots dont les acceptions sont [opposées](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8371023/polysemie), tel le verbe *louer*. Il est une chose que le contexte et quand on parle des *moustaches* d'un animal, on complémente justement avec un nom (*chat, phoque* etc.) ou on est en train de parler de l'anatomie de l'animal etc. Eût-on évoqué directement un *abus de langage* que ce concept aurait pu faire l'objet de [critiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abus_de_langage#Critiques_et_limites). Incidemment la monosémie n'est pas une panacée, même en [terminologie](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/meta/2010-v55-n1-meta3696/039605ar/) et l'[analogie](http://www.culturecommunication.gouv.fr/content/download/93717/841889/file/reperes_2011_termino_neo_def.pdf) participe de la création terminologique.

En parcourant les résultats d'un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moustaches%20*%20chat%2Cmoustache%20*%20chat%2Cvibrisse%20*%20chat%2Cvibrisses%20*%20chat&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3) avec le complément *chat*, on trouve un livre pour enfant où le mot *vibrisse* est employé « Il lui manque quelques poils par-ci par-là et une vibrisse, mais apparemment il a l'air de bien aller » (*L'arbre au soulier d'argent*, C. Boiron) avec une définition en note de bas de page ; un lecteur vante « un vocabulaire soutenu et recherché mais sans difficulté particulière ». L'emploi de termes plus techniques peut avoir cet effet au niveau du [registre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registres_de_langue_en_fran%C3%A7ais) mais on trouve du jargon même dans le registre courant.

---

<sub>Par exemple dans [*Unforgiven*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105695/characters/nm0001321) (1992, Eastwood)

**English Bob** : Little Bill, well I thought you was, well I thought that you were dead. I see you've shaved your *chin whiskers* off.

**Little Bill Daggett** : I was tasting the soup two hours after I ate it.</sub>

Comment: Il y aurait donc le synonyme « soies » , mais je  trouve  préférable de l'utiliser pour nommer ce qui est plus spécifiquement des poils  (comme ceux du cochon). Cet ngram fournit plusieurs exemples d'usage dans des contextes non apparentés à la science, ce qui montre qu'il n'y aurait pas d'opinion contraire à la vulgarisation du mot « vibrisse » ; intéressant… d'une pierre deux coups…